# Azure: how to schedule AzureML scripts taking 1-5 days to complete?

Tags: azure, cron, azure-sql-database, scheduling, azure-machine-learning-service

I have AzureML scripts that take about 1-5 days to complete. All input data comes from Azure SQL and is stored to Azure SQL. The input data is below 10GB.

**What are preferred methods to schedule such scripts inside Azure?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you stumbled onto [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-ml-update-resource-activity)?

Not sure about best practice, but you could set up an update service which can be called using [Azure Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-get-started-portal).

Comment: There are many options: Azure WebJobs, Elastic Jobs, Azure Automation and so forth. Apparently, the limiting factor in Azure [WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/) quickly becomes the RAM. My input data grows from 2GB until 10GB. Compute times is between 1-5 days. Very specific needs.